# How to change battery settings like in Windows. (Power saving, balanced, gaming)

Tags: power-management, battery

Just got Ubuntu a couple of days ago because I wanted to try something new. I'm fond of gaming but I am also recently into programming. Sometimes I have a charger and sometimes I don't. Other than brightness is there any way I could change such settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  If you want something that is fairly straightforward, you can use TLP, which is a command-line power management tool developed by the folks at linrunner (see docs [here](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html)).

Otherwise, check out the Ubuntu Wiki on the subject, it is fairly comprehensive and has some useful tweaks:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerManagement

Comment: Thank you for the links. Lots of help and a lot faster than I figured I would get it!

Comment: Happy to help, @EliMead.